# Jquery AutoComplete Load Problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, json

**Not Work**

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('[id$=Name]').autocomplete('CallBack.aspx',{formatItem: function(item){return item.Name;}}).result(function(event, item) {
            location.href = item.AGE;
        });
```

Json:

```
var data = [{NAME:"John",AGE:"57"}];
```

---

**Work**

**Jquery Code:**

```
var data = [{NAME:"John",AGE:"57"}];

 $('[id$=Name]').autocomplete(data,{formatItem: function(item){return item.Name;}}).result(function(event, item) {
                location.href = item.AGE;
            });
```

[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/119/38235621.jpg](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/119/38235621.jpg)

Help me pls how its make ? callback.aspx return json not work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your data to this:

```
var data = [{id:"John",value:"57"}];
```

***EDIT***

Here's a sample of what I think you're trying to do:

```
var data = [{NAME:"John",AGE:"57"}];

$('[id$=Name]').autocomplete('CallBack.aspx', {
    formatItem: function(item) {
        return item.NAME;
    }}).result(function(event, item) {
            location.href = 'somepage.aspx?age=' + item.AGE;
        });
```

Basically you needed to capitalise `return item.Name` to `return item.NAME`.

Comment: I take it you are using the code at the bottom of this page as your starting point? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete Are you intending to use the selected item in a redirect?

Comment: @Codesleuth selected item redirect test i can selected item hidden field value :-) but cant you see autocomplete list

Comment: my problem callback.aspx get data not work, var data = [{NAME:"John",AGE:"57"}]; Work;

Comment: @Codesleuth my comment edit look pls,var data = [{NAME:"John",AGE:"57"}]; picture work but callback.aspx picture i cant see

Comment: Then it is the result from your callback page that is wrong. You need to paste the code from `CallBack.aspx` for us.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#TextboxId").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { ids: idstopass },

                    success: function (retrieveddata) {

                        alert(retrieveddata);
                        var dData = JSON.parse(retrieveddata);
                        alert(dData.Name);

                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        console.log("Error! " + request.responseText);

                    }
                })
            },


        });
    })
</script>
```